# Calling a "component function" with a click event on a Datatable

Tags: javascript, angular, datatables

In every row of my datatable, I have a . Everytime I click on the  of one row, I manage to "do something" with the data of that row. For instance, I can fire a Swal message, or print something in the console.

The problem is that I cannot call a function there. As you can see in a part of my code, I have the searchMovimientosFunction to construct the datatable and control the "click" event, and then the deleteMovimiento function, as other angular component function.

```
  searchMovimientosFunction(valuesMovimiento) {
  //...here I construct the datatable...

     //...in the function below, I control the click event...
     if (!$.fn.dataTable.isDataTable('#datatables')) {
         $('#datatables tbody td').on('click', 'i', function() {
            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            var row = table.row(tr);
            if (this.className == "deleteButton pe-7s-junk pe-lg pe-va") {
               this.deleteMovimiento("1");  //<--- not working
               //console.log("hello");      //<--- working 
            }
         })
      }
  }

  deleteMovimiento(idMovimiento) {
     console.log(idMovimiento);
  }
```

Do you know how to call the deleteMovimiento function? I've been searching for the answer too much time (in datatables.net, in stackoverflow,...) without success. Any help would be very appreciate.

Comment: Try changing function () { to () => { at minimum

Comment: Since you want `this` to have 2 different values - 1) the clicked DOM element 2) the component instance - within the same function you might want to assign `this` to a variable before the click event registration and use that to invoke any component specific methods.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky, that brought some errors. Maybe it's the first step towards a solution but what PSL said worked right away. Thank you anyway, Alexander.

Comment: @PSL, that worked! Thank you very much. Is it possible to mark a comment as a solution?

Comment: @PSL, do you want to write your comment as the solution to this question? Cheers!